# Array in alphabetical order

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$languages = array('Français' => 'fr', 'English' => 'en');
```

How can I class it in alphabetical order please ?

I try with sort($languages) but it gives me something like (0, 1, ...).

Thanks.

Comment: [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) - sort by value, maintainging associativity (keys)

Comment: You may also want to use [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) - sort by key